# Eclipse+Java+Tomcat - How to setup dynamic web project to refer other java projects

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm creating a web app, for which I have created a dynamic web project in Eclipse. I have also created two java projects, which serve different business purposes. I want my dynamic web project to use these projects as well.

Below are the projects i've created

1. myapp-core (Java project that has all my core components)
2. myapp-db (All classes related to DB calls go here)
3. myappWeb (Dynamic web project which will have only presentation logic)

The point is, I've created all these projects and the classes within them. I have also added myapp-core and myapp-db projects to my myaddWeb's classpath, and am now free of any compilation errors.

However, when I deploy this on Tomcat, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`

Now, all three projects have logging, for which I have added `slf4j` and `logback` related jars to the build paths of each project (separately).

All my projects are referencing common libraries, like guava, apache poi, etc., which I have associated with each project separately.

Am I missing anything here? Can anyone guide me what is the exact setup that needs to be done for such a framework?

Thanks
Sriram

Comment: Did you check webapp lib directory if all jars you need is copied to there?

Comment: Yes i did, and it's all there..

Comment: can you post a snipped screenshot of your lib directory?

Comment: Are you using maven ?

Comment: What do you mean by you've added the other projects/jars to the classpath? Are you really setting them within the classpath of tomcat? Are all jars within the war file? Can you post the directory structure of the war file (not till the end of the java class files but the upmost 4 levels)?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below mentioned steps for all 3 projects :
1. Right Click on your Project
2. Go to "Java EE Module Dependencies" option.
3. Select all jars and Apply changes.

If "Java EE Module Dependencies" is not there, try "Web Deployment Assembly" which does the same thing.